# Using a foreach loop with custom object types in java

Tags: java, object, for-loop, foreach, constructor

In advance I apologize for any mistakes in terminology, it's been a while since I've used java
So I have the constructor

```
Planet[] stars = new Planet [500]
```

The aim is to call a draw() command on each object in stars. Previously I used the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500;, i++)
 stars[i].draw(ss);
```

Although I have recently learnt of the foreach statement, if that is what the colon is called. So instead I try

```
for (int i : stars)
 stars[i].draw(ss);
```

Although upon compiling I receive the error "incompatible types: Planet cannot be converted to int"

I have tried typecasting but it will not allow that either.

Thanks for any help offered

Comment: I would have duplicated to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work esp. the second answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (Planet planet : stars) {
   planet.draw(ss);
}
```